# Communicate to window from iframe on cross-domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

Let's say I have have a webpage with domain name **a.example.com** which has an iframe with domain **b.example.com** (Not satisfying same origin policy).

Now I open a new window using window.open from the iframe with the same domain, that is
**b.example.com**.

My task is to send message back to the iframe.

*window.opener* is empty for the opened window.

I read that I can communicate using postMessage, but to what element I should post the data to. How to get the reference of parent window (i.e the iframe).

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` header

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: I like the idea @PHPglue. But would it possible to bind an event in the opened window so that when click send message in that, the message  should be sent to the iframe.

Comment: Just because you open someone else's web page within your site does not give you access to their page.

Comment: I'm not really understanding your intent. Do you control `a.example.com` or `b.example.com`? Which one do you code `window.open()` on?

Comment: The page inside iframe is under my control which other services are embedding in their sites.
So the window opened from my iframe should be able to send me the data on some action, rite? That's all I want.

Comment: The data of the parent? No. The data of your own page? Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Who says the iframe is yours? The browser can't trust you in this respect because someone could be messing with your page and load something else instead, so modern browsers lock iframe communication down completely. Even with access control, you won't get two way communication going.

However, if you can make the iframe and the owning document "speak the same language", then you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) communication: postMessage basically posts strings (and *only* strings, so any JS objects need to be JSON.stringified) into a "visible to everyone" bucket of strings. Any document context can post messages, and every context can decide to listen to whether new messages are posted. If they are, then you can make the iframe send messages that the owning window can parse, and vice versa.

Comment: "speak the same language" means they should satify same origin policy?
If that's the thing, it's not possible to do that. I just need to get the data (yes it's string) from opened window to the iframe.

Comment: The page inside iframe is under my control which other services are embedding in their sites. So the window opened from my iframe should be able to send me the data back on some event.

Comment: no, they literally need to be able to parse the strings that the other dumps into the message pool. The only way you can get data from the owner is by postMessaging a request *that the owner knows means a request*, and then have the owner respond with its own message *that your iframe knows how to parse* again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to for their site, which holds the `iframe` that you control the contents of, to get information back from a window that is opened by clicking something within your contents, they have to allow access to your site on theirs. If you just want data from a window that is opened by clicking something on the page that you control it's like:

```
var newWindow = open('yourURL.php');
var someElement = newWindow.document.getElementById('someId');
console.log(someElement.value); // assuming it's an input
```

If you want information from the page that opened your other page from withing the newly opened window it's like:

```
var openerElement = opener.document.getElementById('openerWindowId');
console.log(openerElement.innerHTML); // assuming it's not an input
```

Comment: Then how to bind the click event so once the button is pressed, then I only can get the data in my iframe.
Initially, as you mentioned 'someElement' will be blank. Unless user enters the data and clicks the 'send' button then we should get the data by your approach ie. 'newWindow.document.getElementById('someId');

Comment: You really need to ignore the iframe altogether, if you don't control it. Do everything like it doesn't even exist. `newWindow.document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = function(){/* don't use newWindow and you are talking about current window */};` I'm not really sure what you don't get here.